# How do I do a Bootstrap responsive table inside another table?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4. In my project I need toggle responsive table inside another table. When I click to expand show inner table and again click collapse inner table like below Image.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this code for  toggle responsive table inside another table**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Column</th>
               <th>Column</th>
               <th>Column</th>
               <th>Column</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#group-of-rows-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="group-of-rows-1">
               <td><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
               <td>data</td>
               <td>data</td>
               <td>data</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
         <tbody id="group-of-rows-1" class="collapse">
            <tr>
               <td>- child row</td>
               <td>data 1</td>
               <td>data 1</td>
               <td>data 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>- child row</td>
               <td>data 1</td>
               <td>data 1</td>
               <td>data 1</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
         <tbody>
            <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#group-of-rows-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="group-of-rows-2">
               <td><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
               <td>data</td>
               <td>data</td>
               <td>data</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
         <tbody id="group-of-rows-2" class="collapse">
            <tr>
               <td>- child row</td>
               <td>data 2</td>
               <td>data 2</td>
               <td>data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>- child row</td>
               <td>data 2</td>
               <td>data 2</td>
               <td>data 2</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But in mobile view large data to table appear horizontal scroller.